# Two index computations differing in execution time

Tags: c, assembly, casting

### Code

I have the following piece of code

```
        #define equidIND(divid, recip) (size_t)((divid) * (recip) + 0.5)
        ...
        // Get index for average velocity
        //idx_velo_avg    = (size_t)(velo_avg * funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip + 0.5);
        idx_velo_avg = equidIND(velo_avg, funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip);
        // Get effective velocity
        velo_eff = sqrt(velo_pos_k * velo_pos_k + accel * delta_s);
        // Get index for effective velocity (HOTSPOT)
        idx_velo_eff = equidIND(velo_eff, funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip);
```

### Explanation

It contains three lines with operations

- **First line** - `idx_velo_avg = ...`  Getting index by value using rounding/NNinterpolation:

  1. Mapping value to index by division turned into a multiplication with the reciprocal:
     `velo_avg * funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip`
  2. Adding `0.5` to the resulting double
  3. Truncating using a cast `(size_t)`. The values are always `> 0` btw.
- The **second line** computes then the effective velocity, using a call to `sqrt`.
- The **third line** does ***exactly*** the same as the first, but with a different base value (first line `velo_avg` - third line `velo_eff`)

### Profiling

[Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) and [AMD CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/) give similar profiling results

[image: code]
The snapshot is taken from [AMD CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/).

### Question(s)

What I wonder is:

1. **Is this way of computing an index a good, fast and secure one?**
2. **Why does the third line apparently more than 4 times slower than the first**. At least this is how I interpret the percentage values in CodeXL and Very Sleepy kind of confirms this interpretation. Has it to do with the intermediate call to `sqrt`?

### ASM

As additional information, the assembly view shows the following ([link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9KgQ.png))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These two statements are functionally identical:

```
idx_velo_avg = (size_t)((velo_avg) * (funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip) + 0.5);

idx_velo_eff = (size_t)((velo_eff) * (funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip) + 0.5);
```

The only difference is the variable on the left side of the multiplication. Since `velo_eff` is calculated just before the second of these statements, we can safely assume that the slowdown isn't caused by a cache miss.

So I think the only possible explanation is that the processor has to wait for the result of the square root calculation to emerge from the processing pipeline before it can start calculating `idx_velo_eff`.

Try calculating the square root first, and see if that helps:

```
velo_eff = sqrt(velo_pos_k * velo_pos_k + accel * delta_s);
idx_velo_avg = equidIND(velo_avg, funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip);
idx_velo_eff = equidIND(velo_eff, funmaps_velo->map_velo_step_recip);
```

Also, check your compiler optimization settings. A decent compiler should be able to do this sort of thing for you.